# Utilize XMLHttpRequest on Real Time HighChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, ajax, highcharts

I am writing a revision of Dynamic HighChart which allows real time data [(js fiddle example)](http://jsfiddle.net/technologrich/qrTeQ/). I would like to be able to perform a query on a separate page and process it via the XMLHttpRequest Ajax command. However, I have never utilized this command, nor understand how I could incorporate it into the following code:

```
        events : {
            load : function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time

                    //y contains the next dynamic point
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
```

So, How would I incorporate the XMLHttpRequest into the code? As well as not have it overlap while awaiting response back from the SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off if you moved to a `setTimeout` in the "success" handler of the ajax call then using  `setIntervals` that could stomp on each other.

```
// define your ajax function
// note I am using jquery's .ajax --> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
// it is just easier than writing your own cross browser XMLHttpRequest
ajaxCall =  function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some/URL",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function( rJson ) {
        var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
        var series = chart.series[0];
        // do something to chart
        series.addPoint([rJson.x, rJson.y], true, true);
        // call this again when ajax call completes...
        setTimeout(ajaxCall, 1000);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" ); //do something if ajax fails
    })
}
```

Now in the chart chart load callback get it rolling...

```
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    chart : {
        events : {
            load : function() {
                setTimeout(ajaxCall, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll try it out today and let you know. Thanks!